# async in a microservice architecture

Tags: asynchronous, architecture

Let's say we have a web application in microservice architecture, where there is an API gateway and a couple of micro services. For scalability, one has to take advantage of async network operation. But my question is: is this async only required at the API gateway level or is it required at all services? Why?

Answer (score 0):

You should implements async in all services, include gateway api. If not, your whole system may implicit bottle neck.

For http, you may need to use some stateful platform, like java. PHP (or something like that) under webserver (apache, nginx) don't give you async mechanism.